# Why can I not add an object to a list?

Tags: c#, list, methods, console

(Get all c# files at the bottom)

I have made a list of Pizza-objects in my class "Menu". I have a problem when I am trying to add an object of my Pizza-class to the list (again from the Menu-class):

(BTW I have tried to translate, but I'm sorry - some of it is in danish as part of an assignment - but comments above is the translation)

```
            //add to menu
    public void TilføjTilMenukort()
    {          
        //"add element to the menu?"
        Console.WriteLine("Tilføj element til menuen? j/n");
        svar = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        if(svar == 'j')
        {   
            //enter number
            Console.WriteLine("Indtast nummer");
            int newNr = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            //enter name
            Console.WriteLine("\nIndtast navn");
            string newNavn = Console.ReadLine();

            //enter ingredient
            Console.WriteLine("\nIndtast ingredienser adskilt med ','");
            string newIngrediens = Console.ReadLine();

            //enter price
            Console.WriteLine("\nIndtast pris"); 
            double newPris = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            //list name is "pizza on menu"
            PizzaPaaMenu.Add(new Pizza(newNr, newNavn, newIngrediens, newPris));
        }
    }
```

It is as if the object is added to the list, because after this I call a method which is writing each element of the list - and it appears on the list!:

```
    //show menu
    public void VisMenu()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Menu:\n");

        foreach (Pizza p in PizzaPaaMenu)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}. {1} - {2} - {3} kr.\n", p.Nr, p.PizzaNavn, p.Ingrediens, p.Pris);
        }
    }
```

But when I try to run another method from another class (ordering) afterwards - it keeps returning the line saying that the pizza was not found:

```
    Console.WriteLine("\nPizzaen med nr. " + bestilNummer + " blev ikke fundet!");
```

..which is found further down in this block of code:

```
    //create order
    public void OpretBestilling()
    {
        do
        {
            //"which number from the menu do you want?"
            Console.WriteLine("\nHvilket nummer fra menuen ønsker du at bestille?");
            //orderNumber
            int bestilNummer = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            //orderPizza
            Pizza bestiltPizza = null;

            Menukort menukort = new Menukort();

            //The pizzas is searched through for the pizza with number "bestilNummer"("orderNumber")),
            foreach (Pizza p in menukort.PizzaPaaMenu)
            {
                if (p.Nr == bestilNummer)
                {
                    //if it is found in the list "PizzaPaaMenu", "bestiltPizza" points to the pizza being added (pizza p)
                    bestiltPizza = p;
                    break;
                }
            }
            //if it is a "real" pizza (not null / p), it gets added to the list "BestillingsListe" ("order-list")
            if (bestiltPizza != null)
            {
                BestillingsListe.Add(bestiltPizza);
                //"the pizza is added to your order"
                Console.WriteLine("\n" + bestiltPizza.PizzaNavn + " er tilføjet til bestillingen");
                //"do you wish to order more?"
                Console.WriteLine("\nØnsker du at bestille mere? j/n");
                done = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }else{
                //"Pizza x was not found"
                Console.WriteLine("\nPizzaen med nr. " + bestilNummer + " blev ikke fundet!");
            }
        } while (done == 'j');
    }
```

The important code in my Main method looks like this:

```
    //should add a pizza-object to the list of pizzas in "menu"
                    menukort.TilføjTilMenukort();

                    //runs through the list of pizza-objects
                    menukort.VisMenu();

                    //"do you wish to order?"
                    Console.WriteLine("\nØnsker du at bestille? j/n");
                    charsvar = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    if (charsvar == 'j')
                    {   //creates an order by making sure, that the pizza exists in the list from "menu"
                        bestilling.OpretBestilling();
                        //shows what has been ordered
                        bestilling.VisBestilling();
```

...

Thanks!

[Get all files](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10599790/Digital%20menu.zip)

Comment: Pizza Class definition??

Comment: `PizzaPaaMenu` definition?? From this I can only guess, that `PizzaPaaMenu` is not the same thing as `menukort.PizzaPaaMenu`.

Comment: Are your sure "menukort" is the same instance as the one you added the items to earlier? There could be an instantiation you aren't showing that is breaking it.

Comment: You are creating a new instance of `Menukort` right before looping through the pizzas in it. Do you copy the pizzas from somewhere when you create the instance, or does it start with an empty list?

Comment: Sorry guys. It's hard as i'm new at this.. Look at the code here: [link](http://pastebin.com/3WK4xWgZ)

Comment: @Guffa It starts out as a list of 8 pizzas as soon as the instance is created.
So perhaps, BradleyDotNET, you are right - I just can't figure out where..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Bestilling` class is not aware of the `Menukort` instance that you use in the main program. It creates its own instance, which is a separate list of pizzas from the one that you have been working with up til then.

Instead of creating a new instance of `Menukort` in the `Bestilling` class, you should send the instance that you use into it:

```
Menukort menukort = new Menukort();
Bestilling bestilling = new Bestilling(menukort);
```

Declare a variable in the `Bestilling` class for it:

```
class Bestilling
{
    private Menukort menukort;
    ...
```

In the constructor you get the reference to the instance and put in the variable:

```
public Bestilling(Menukort kort) {
  menukort = kort;
}
```

Remove the line that creates the new instance (342), and the rest of the code will be the same, using the variable that you added to the class instead.

---

Translation for our english viewers:

> Bestilling = Food order
>   Menukort = Menu sheet